# SQL 2008 install on Windows Server 2008 Permission Denied errors

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008

When trying to install SQL 2008 on W2K8 I get about 6 permission denied errors even though I'm installing logged on as a domain admin?

Any one else experienced this?

Thanks

John

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068643839
  Exit facility code:            1203
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  SQL Server installation failed. To continue, investigate the reason for the failure, correct the problem, uninstall SQL Server, and then rerun SQL Server Setup.
  Start time:                    2009-06-23 10:11:08
  End time:                      2009-06-24 11:25:01
  Requested action:              Install
  Log with failure:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt
  Exception help link:           http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%3fLinkId%3d20476%26ProdName%3dMicrosoft%2bSQL%2bServer%26EvtSrc%3dsetup.rll%26EvtID%3d50000%26ProdVer%3d10.0.1600.22%26EvtType%3d0x44D4F75E%400xFB92A9BB

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  CDA-APPS1
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows Server 2008
  OS service pack:               Service Pack 1
  OS region:                     United Kingdom
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
  Sql Server 2005      BKUPEXEC             MSSQL.1                        Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        
  Sql Server 2005      BKUPEXEC             MSSQL.1                        SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        
  Sql Server 2005      BKUPEXEC             MSSQL.1                        SharedTools                              1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        
  Sql Server 2005                                                          Tools                                    1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        
  Sql Server 2005                                                          ToolsClient                              1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        
  Sql Server 2005                                                          ToolsClient\Connectivity                 1033                 Express Edition      9.2.3042        No        

Package properties:
  Description:                   SQL Server Database Services 2008
  SQLProductFamilyCode:          {628F8F38-600E-493D-9946-F4178F20A8A9}
  ProductName:                   SQL2008
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       10
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          STANDARD

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      False
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 user\dcsqlagent
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config
  ASDATADIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data
  ASDOMAINGROUP:                 <empty>
  ASLOGDIR:                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  user\dcsqladmin
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            USER\DBAdmins,USER\DCSQLAgent,USER\DCAdmin
  ASTEMPDIR:                     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENABLERANU:                    False
  ERRORREPORTING:                False
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE,REPLICATION,FULLTEXT,AS,RS,BIDS,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,BOL,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,OCS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  HELP:                          False
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              False
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             G:\Data
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server 2008
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MEDIASOURCE:                   D:\
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         False
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   False
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  USER\DCSQLAdmin
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 *****
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  <empty>
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  I:\Backups
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 user\dcsqladmin
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           USER\DBAdmins,USER\DCSQLAgent,USER\DCSQLAdmin
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               H:\Logs\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  G:\UserDB
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               H:\Logs
  SQMREPORTING:                  False
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  X86:                           False

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0xFB92A9BB
  Configuration error description: Access is denied
  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0xFB92A9BB
  Configuration error description: Access is denied
  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt

  Feature:                       Full-Text Search
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0xFB92A9BB
  Configuration error description: Access is denied
  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt

  Feature:                       Analysis Services
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Reporting Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Failed: see details below
  Configuration error code:      0xFB92A9BB
  Configuration error description: Access is denied
  Configuration log:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt

  Feature:                       Integration Services
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools SDK
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Business Intelligence Development Studio
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Server Books Online
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

  Feature:                       Microsoft Sync Framework
  Status:                        Passed
  MSI status:                    Passed
  Configuration status:          Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have User Access Control turned on? If UAC is on then even members of the Administrators group don't have the same access as the Administrator account. You have to either turn UAC off or log on as Administrator.

JR

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20090623_100158\Detail.txt  ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you a sysadmin within the SQL Server?  This will be required in order to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

UAC is in effect in Server 2008 just like Vista.  Logging in as a member of the Domain Admins group means nothing if you're not running processes elevated.  Though I'm somewhat surprised the SQL 2008 installer didn't prompt for elevation on its own.  In any case, you should be able to right click the setup.exe and choose "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...  Are you trying to upgrade your existing SQL 2005 instance(s) or to install an additional SQL 2008 instance?  If it's not a UAC thing as mentioned by others and you are trying to install a new instance, then make sure you're choosing a different instance name then what you have already installed and that you're also not trying to install SQL 2008 as the default instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also have DEBUG PROGRAMS and MANAGE AUDITING AND SECURITY LOGS privileges.